# Loop take too much time to execute the code

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel file I have 600000 rows and below code take too much time to execute. It is getting 150 rows in 1 minuter. Any suggestion to improve the below code?

```vb
For i = 2 To UBound(vArray, 1)
    With Worksheets(1).Range("C2:C" & Z)
        Set c = .Find(Sheet2.Cells(i, "A"), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstaddress = c.Address
            Do
              If Sheet2.Cells(i, "A") = Sheet.Cells(c.Row, 3) Then
                 If UCase(Sheet1.Cells(c.Row, "D")) = "AVDELING" Then
                    Sheet2.Cells(i, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(c.Row, 5)
                 ElseIf UCase(Sheet1.Cells(c.Row, "D")) = "PROSJEKT" Then
                    Sheet2.Cells(i, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(c.Row, 5)
                 End If
             End If
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                If firstaddress = c.Address Then
                    GoTo end_this
                End If
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing
        End If
    End With
end_this:
Next i
```

Comment: What you have provided is not enough for us to answer.  We would need the code inside the loop.  But having said that, this question is better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com  But before you post there make sure you read what is expected for a good question.  They want a lot more information.

Comment: Z gets 600000 rows in varray I have 104000

Comment: How big does `UBound(vArray, 1)` get?

Comment: I get 104000 rows in varray

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: Update your question if you want to add code - it's unreadable in a comment

Comment: I have updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using memory arrays rather than Excel ranges for searching and storing your results.  The code below executes in a few seconds.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim findWhat() As Variant
  Dim findIn() As Variant
  Dim rowNum As Long
  Dim findIndex As Long
  Dim results() As Variant

  findWhat = Array("A10", "B5", "C3")
  findIn = Range("A1:A640000").Value
  results = Range("B1:D640000").Value

  For findIndex = LBound(findWhat) To UBound(findWhat)
    For rowNum = LBound(findIn) To UBound(findIn)
      If findWhat(findIndex) = findIn(rowNum, 1) Then
        results(rowNum, 1) = "Found " & findIndex
      End If
    Next rowNum
  Next findIndex

  Range("B1:D640000").Value = results
End Sub
```